# Fix problem of removed code still executing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having the strangest problem with a WordPress plugin I'm writing. I've been working on the plugin for a few weeks, and this problem just occurred.

In troubleshooting an order of execution, I decided to comment out some code. However, when I activate the plugin, I receive a fatal error indicating Apache is still trying to execute the code.

Here's the function in question from includes/WPSCAPLogger/WPSCAPLogger.php:

```
function logMessage($logType, $message) {
    try {
        global $tablePrefix;
        global $wpdb;
        $tablePrefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $tableName = $tablePrefix . 'wpscap_log_category';
        $result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT id FROM {$tableName} WHERE log_category LIKE '{$logType}'", OBJECT );
        $logTypeID = $result->id;
        $tableName = $tablePrefix . 'wpscap_log';
        $data = array('log_category_id' => $logTypeID, 'log_entry' => $message);

        $wpdb->insert($tableName, $data);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Critical error with logger.');
        // TO DO: Handle this better -- or default to PHP error log?
    }
}
```

I commented everything in the try block, which is lines 4 through 17. Then I received the following error in the application:

> [Table 'bsd_dev.wp_wpscap_log_category' doesn't exist]
>   SELECT id FROM wp_wpscap_log_category WHERE log_category LIKE 'Error'
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\battlestardigital\wp-content\plugins\stripe-connect-auto-provision\includes\WPSCAPLogger\WPSCAPLogger.php
>   on line 12 WordPress database error: [Table 'bsd_dev.wp_wpscap_log'
>   doesn't exist] SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_wpscap_log`
>
> WordPress database error: [Table 'bsd_dev.wp_wpscap_log_category'
>   doesn't exist] SELECT id FROM wp_wpscap_log_category WHERE
>   log_category LIKE 'Error'
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\battlestardigital\wp-content\plugins\stripe-connect-auto-provision\includes\WPSCAPLogger\WPSCAPLogger.php
>   on line 12 WordPress database error: [Table 'bsd_dev.wp_wpscap_log'
>   doesn't exist] SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_wpscap_log`

I thought that was weird, so I deleted the plugin, made sure the lines were commented out, restarted XAMPP, and reinstalled. Same error. Then I restarted my machine, still got the same error.

Finally, I opened the file inside of WordPress itself and deleted the lines, fixing the `die` line as well. The entire function now looks like this:

```
function logMessage($logType, $message) {
    try {

    } catch (Exception $e) {            
        error_log($e, 0);
    }
}
```

I also opened WordPress in my code editor and searched the entire code base for "wpscap_log_category". I found it in debug.log and in the class that creates the table, as expected, nowhere else.

Then, I attempted to activate the plugin again. The plugin actually does create the table, but I still receive the same error.

This seems like such a strange thing to be troubleshooting! Suggestions?

**EDIT** I also cleared my cache in Chrome, but that didn't help. I tried in Edge; same result.

**EDIT #2** I was never able to solve this. I installed a new test site in XAMPP and uploaded the plugin, where it worked just fine. Clearly there was a caching issue, despite having cleared the cache several times. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

What if you open it in another browser? Does the same issue still occur? 
I could be a caching issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried clearing Chrome's cache, to no effect. I just tried uploading it through Edge; same result.